# How to make dots in an matplotlib animation disappear?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am making an animation in matplotlib, where dots are moving in a certain direction. I would like them to disappear, when they reach a given value.
In the following code, the dots are moving in a U shape and stop at the end.
I would like the dots to disappear, when they stop, at `x= 7-9`, `y=7`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import random

n_particles = 40
b_particles=5
box_width = 10
n_steps = 5000
dt = 0.001

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
# -------
def get_initial_coordinates():

    x=[random.uniform(2,3) for i in range(n_particles)]
    y=[random.uniform(2,7) for i in range(n_particles)]
    return x,y
def get_initial_velocities():
    directions=[np.array([0,1]),np.array([1,0]),np.array([-1,0]),np.array([0,-1])]
    direction=random.choice(directions)
    d1 = []
    for i in range(n_particles):
        d1.append(random.choice(directions))
    d1 = np.array(d1)

    xv=[ 0  for i in range(n_particles)]
    yv=[ -20  for i in range(n_particles)]

    return xv, yv
throughwall = []
for i in range(n_particles):
    throughwall.append(random.random() * 100)
def take_step(x,y,xv,yv):
    for i in range(n_particles):
     x[i] +=xv[i]*dt
     y[i] +=yv[i]*dt
     if y[i] <= random.uniform(-1,3):
        xv[i] = 20
        yv[i]=0
     if x[i] >=random.uniform(7,10):
         xv[i]=0
         yv[i]= 20
     if y[i] >=7 and 7<x[i]<9:
         xv[i]=0
         yv[i]=0
    return x,y,xv,yv
x,y = get_initial_coordinates()
xv,yv= get_initial_velocities()
for i in range(n_steps):
    x,y,xv,yv= take_step(x,y,xv,yv)
#---------------------
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
e, = ax.plot([x[i] for i in range(n_particles)],
             [y[i] for i in range(n_particles)], 'ro')
x,y= get_initial_coordinates()
xv,yv= get_initial_velocities()

import matplotlib.patches as patches

ax.add_patch(
     patches.Rectangle(
        (3, 3),4,4,edgecolor = 'blue', fill=False) )
ax.add_patch(
     patches.Rectangle(
        (2, 2),6,5,edgecolor = 'blue',fill=False) )
def animate(i):
    take_step(x,y,xv,yv)
    e.set_data([x[i]for i in range(n_particles)],
               [y[i] for i in range(n_particles)])
    return e,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the particle reaches the end, one could set its position far outside the view. The code below sets the `y` at 1000. As the view limits (`xlim` and `ylim`) aren't changed, the dot will be invisible.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import random

n_particles = 40
b_particles = 5
box_width = 10
dt = 0.001

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

def get_initial_coordinates():
    x = np.random.uniform(2, 3, n_particles)
    y = np.random.uniform(2, 7, n_particles)
    return x, y

def get_initial_velocities():
    xv = np.zeros(n_particles)
    yv = np.zeros(n_particles) - 20
    return xv, yv

def take_step(x, y, xv, yv):
    for i in range(n_particles):
        x[i] += xv[i] * dt
        y[i] += yv[i] * dt
        if y[i] <= random.uniform(-1, 3):
            xv[i] = 20
            yv[i] = 0
        if x[i] >= random.uniform(7, 10):
            xv[i] = 0
            yv[i] = 20
        if y[i] >= 7 and 7 < x[i] < 9:
            xv[i] = 0
            yv[i] = 0
        if y[i] >= 7 and x[i] >= 7:
            y[i] = 10000
    return x, y, xv, yv

x, y = get_initial_coordinates()
xv, yv = get_initial_velocities()
e, = ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')

ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (3, 3), 4, 4, edgecolor='blue', fill=False))
ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (2, 2), 6, 5, edgecolor='blue', fill=False))

def animate(i):
    take_step(x, y, xv, yv)
    e.set_data(x, y)
    return e,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

An alternative could be to draw a reservoir where the particles will stop. Making the reservoir white, and setting its `zorder` higher than the dots (default the dots get `zorder` 2) will make the dots hidden. For the reservoir not to hide the border of the U shape, the rectangles of the U shape can get a still higher `zorder`.

The code below lets the particles stop near `y == 7.5` to make sure they arrive at the center of the reservoir.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import random

n_particles = 40
b_particles = 5
box_width = 10
dt = 0.001

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

def get_initial_coordinates():
    x = np.random.uniform(2, 3, n_particles)
    y = np.random.uniform(2, 7, n_particles)
    return x, y

def get_initial_velocities():
    xv = np.zeros(n_particles)
    yv = np.zeros(n_particles) - 20
    return xv, yv

def take_step(x, y, xv, yv):
    for i in range(n_particles):
        x[i] += xv[i] * dt
        y[i] += yv[i] * dt
        if y[i] <= random.uniform(-1, 3):
            xv[i] = 20
            yv[i] = 0
        if x[i] >= random.uniform(7, 10):
            xv[i] = 0
            yv[i] = 20
        if y[i] >= 7.5 and 7 < x[i] < 9:
            xv[i] = 0
            yv[i] = 0
    return x, y, xv, yv

x, y = get_initial_coordinates()
xv, yv = get_initial_velocities()
e, = ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')

ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (3, 3), 4, 4, edgecolor='blue', fill=False, zorder=4))
ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (2, 2), 6, 5, edgecolor='blue', fill=False, zorder=4))
# draw the reservoir, white makes it invisible, change its color
#   to `facecolor='gold', alpha=0.5` to see what's happening
ax.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle(
        (6, 7), 3, 1, edgecolor='none', facecolor='white', zorder=3))

def animate(i):
    take_step(x, y, xv, yv)
    e.set_data(x, y)
    return e,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution was so easy and creative, I regret it's not my idea.